# Why did Machir have to conquer Gil'ad?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, mattos

I'm trying to "coordinate" my understanding of various verses regarding what happened with Gil'ad as referenced in parshat Matot.

1. [Bemidbar 32:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=422) The tribes of Gad and Re'uven see that the lands of Ya'azer and Gilad are good pasture land and they desire to inhabit these areas.
2. [Bemidbar 32:3-4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=424) In verse 3, the tribes mention specific cities, which does not include mentioning Gil'ad. In verse 4 they say "**the land** that G-d has conquered for us..." -

I'm assuming that they mean all the land which includes Gil'ad and not the specific cities that they mentioned. Though, I'm not 100% sure of this. Did G-d help conquer the land of Gil'ad, also?

3. [Bemidbar 32:33](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=434) Moshe includes part of the tribe of Menashe together with Reuven and Gad. He gives them the entire land of the Sichon the Emori.

Question - Did Sihon own Gil'ad as well?

4. [Bemidbar 32:39](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=436) Machir ben Mensahse conquers Gil'ad and gains the land that the Emori lived in.

   Are these additional Emori that lived there outside the territory of Sihon? Did G-d **not** help conquer the area of Gil'ad? Refer back to my question after #2.